# How to havev multiple check loop as if it was an if/elseif loop in glue Then in serenity bdd Java

Tags: serenity-bdd

I have this code

` and(theActorInTheSpotlight()).attemptsTo(

```
            Check.whether(Presence.of(PaginaBizagiCTAAperturaCuenta.A_TIT_INF_CLIENTE.waitingForNoMoreThan(Duration.ofSeconds(3))))
                    .andIfSo(
                            //Ensure here
                    ).otherwise(
                            //Ensure default
                    )

    );`
```

I want something like

and(theActorInTheSpotlight()).attemptsTo(

```
            Check.whether(Presence.of(PaginaBizagiCTAAperturaCuenta.A_TIT_INF_CLIENTE.waitingForNoMoreThan(Duration.ofSeconds(3))))
                    .andIfSo(
                            //Ensure here
                    ).otherwiseIfCondition#2(
                            //Ensure #2).otherwise(
                            //Ensure default)
                    )

    );
```

Tried to look other if else loop for serenity.screenplay.conditions but is limitated